# How can I display dynamic column names returned from a stored procedure in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a stored procedure that returns data in the following format:

```
|username| dynamicDate1 | dynamicDate2 | dynamicDate3 | dynamicDatex|
|userxyz |            n |            n |            n |            n|
```

The number of columns returned is dependent on @datestart and @dateend report parameters. How can I bind my matrix to this data without knowing what date range will be selected?

I'm using visual studio 2013 with SQL Data Services v12

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the stored procedure, change it to return an un-pivoted dataset, and have the matrix pivot it for you since it will expand and shrink the number of columns based on what is in the result set and column grouping. Trying this any other way is a form of torture that you do not want to experience.

If you cannot change the stored procedure, you can write a new one that takes the results from the current one, and un-pivots the results before SSRS get them? I am assuming the DBMS is SQL Server. [PIVOT/UNPIVOT Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, agree. I've had enough torture trying to research this. I'll get the stored proc un-pivoted and make an attempt at letting ssrs do the pivot. The DBA that built the stored proc specializes in SSRS I'm wondering why he didn't insist on returning the data un-pivoted in the first place.